# How to make Debian consider a data file as text?

Tags: file, command-line, debian

Sorry for this bad title.
Here is my problem : I have a PHP file (which works fine in Production btw), considered as "DATA" or "BINARY" by the OS ! (Debian Wheezy)

For instance :

```
stack:~/# file test/foo.php
test/foo.php: PHP script, UTF-8 Unicode text

stack:~/# file test/bar.php
test/bar.php: data
```

I just don't know :

- How does it happen ?
- How can I fix it ? (*foo/bar.php* is truly a text
  file)

I read about `file` command, who read the X bytes and check for a NUL value. Ok, but how can I fix my file ? Copy it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show `bar.php` ?

Comment: Well it's a 1788 Lines script, I cannot share it ;)

Comment: Is it a problem that the `file` command sees this as data? This is just a heuristic, and should have no consequences otherwise on the usability of the file as a PHP file. There is nothing "wrong" with your PHP file just because the `file` command doesn't recognise it.

Comment: At least the very first characters of your file would be good to know. Note that this is not an issue as file is more of an informative tool than a real recognition.

Comment: @geert3 : actually, Gedit and Geany cannot open this file, with an error message about "binary file". So yes, it was a problem ;) PatJ : It was not the first, but the very last line !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you open the file with VI for example ?

And see at the very beguinning (or the very last) of the file, if you can see any special chars (hexadecimal, etc).

Comment: Or with emacs with hexa-mod.

Comment: Holly crap, you're right !! Thank you man. VIm show me that, in the very last line : `1789 ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`. How does this happen ?!